# Button enable and disable on click on same coordinates angular

Tags: angular, button

I have a requirement in which when I right click inside a div with contents, a copy button will display there and on clicking on the copy button, it will copy content. Everything is working fine except the copy button position. I have to display the button where ever I right click. I dont know how to implement that in angular.

I think I have to find out the coordinates and display the button there. Is it possible?

```html
<div (contextmenu)="onRightClick(id)">{{textContnet}}</div>
this.enableCopyButton = false;
 onRightClick(id: number) {
        this.enableCopyButton = true;
        return false;
    }
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Please check my answer and the stackblitz link and let me know it worked for you not. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. You can use `mouseMove`,`click` event and `hidden` property to do that. Please check my code and the demo link given below=>

**TS:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mouse-move',
  template: `
   <div (mousemove)="mouseMove($event)" (click)="onClick($event)">
    <button [hidden]="isVisible" #mytarget [ngStyle]="myFinalStyle">TypeScipt</button>
   </div>
  `,
  styles: [`div {
     background: tomato;
     width: 200px;
     height: 300px;
     }`]
})
export class MouseMoveComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @ViewChild('mytarget') targetElement: any; 
  isHidden:boolean=true;
  myFinalStyle:any;
  lastClientX:any;
  lastClientY:any;
  mouseMove(e) {
    this.lastClientX=e.clientX;
    this.lastClientY=e.clientY;
    console.log('Position x:'  + e.clientX + 'Position y:' + e.clientY);
  }
  onClick(event: any) {
    this.isHidden=false;
    const height = this.targetElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    console.log(height);
    const width = this.targetElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    console.log(width);
    let myX=(this.lastClientX - (width/2)).toString()+'px';
    let myY=(this.lastClientY-(height/2)-2).toString()+'px';
     let temp = {
        ['margin-left']: myX,
        ['margin-top']: myY
    };
     this.myFinalStyle=temp;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Please check the demo link in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mouse-move-lwbgjp?file=app%2Fmouse-move.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an example for you.

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="box" #box>
  Right click here!
</div>

<div class="menu" #menu>
  <ul class="menu-options">
    <li class="menu-option">Copy</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**TS**:

```js
@ViewChild('menu') contextMenu: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  @ViewChild('box') box: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  showMenu: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}
  setMenuPosition(position) {
    this.contextMenu.nativeElement.style.left = `${position.left}px`;
    this.contextMenu.nativeElement.style.top = `${position.top}px`;

    this.toggleContextMenu('show');
  }

  toggleContextMenu(state) {
    this.contextMenu.nativeElement.style.display =
      state === 'show' ? 'block' : 'none';
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
  }

  fireContextMenu() {
    this.box.nativeElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const origin = {
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY,
      };
      this.setMenuPosition(origin);
      return false;
    });
    this.contextMenu.nativeElement.childNodes.forEach((contextMenuItems) => {
      contextMenuItems.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.toggleContextMenu('hide');

        console.log(e);

        // do somting
      });
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.fireContextMenu();
  }
```

and finally in **SCSS** file:

```css
.menu {
    min-width: 200px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    .menu-options {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
        .menu-option {
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
            cursor: pointer;

            &:hover {
                background: #a7a7a7;
            }
        }
    }
}

.box {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

[Demo & Source Code in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-context-menu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)